# 'Series' object has no attribute 'isoweekday'

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following data, although I have months and months of data, I have projected here only few days data
I tried to use the following code to get last 15 days data, but I always land on following error

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'isoweekday'
```

Need help here

My code:

```
import datetime

df['Data_Date'] = datetime.date.today()

weekday = df['Data_Date'].isoweekday()

start = df["Data_Date"] - datetime.timedelta(days=weekday)

dates = [start - datetime.timedelta(days=d) for d in range(15)]

df["Data_Date"] = [str(d) for d in dates]
```

Data

```
Data_Date  File  Data
2021-03-06  18  1144396
2021-03-06  12  1069004
2021-03-06  11  2050459
2021-03-06  18  1648709
2021-03-07  18  1131606
2021-03-07  11  1069685
2021-03-07  11  2062713
2021-03-07  18  1594153
2021-03-08  18  1161566
2021-03-08  18  1068366
2021-03-08  18  2048878
2021-03-08  18  1649411
2021-03-09  19  1257021
2021-03-09  18  1055597
2021-03-09  18  2026171
2021-03-09  19  1792446
2021-03-10  18  1164453
2021-03-10  12  1088292
2021-03-10  12  2073664
2021-03-10  12  1658517
2021-03-11  12  1140799
2021-03-11  12  1030003
2021-03-11  12  1995509
2021-03-11  12  1614548
```

[image]

Comment: Can you add expected ouput? Why there is range15 ?

Comment: As i said i have month of data, but i want only last 15 days data, so i used the code with range 15. Following output i reqd. i closed the pivot part. Following output Date_Date Sum of Data
2021-03-02 6131235
2021-03-03 5984926
2021-03-04 5780859
2021-03-05 6131235
2021-03-06 5912568
2021-03-07 5858157
2021-03-08 5928221
2021-03-09 6131235
2021-03-10 5984926
2021-03-11 5780859
2021-03-12 6131235
2021-03-13 6131235
2021-03-14 6131235
2021-03-15 6131235
2021-03-16 6131235

Comment: In data is 24 rows, so need filter them?

Comment: There is some datetims before processing? Or youi create new column `Data_Date` ?

Comment: So need processing some another data and need some another ouput not from question?

Comment: my actual date format was 20210317used the following code to format the date                   df['Data_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Data_Date'], format='%Y%m%d')

df["Data_Date"] = df["Data_Date"].dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

Comment: Can you show input data and expected ouput?

Comment: input data                                                                                                           Data_Date Data
20210311 1762439
20210312 1678808
20210312 1665741
20210312 3043567
20210312 2362461
20210313 1166616
20210313 1156903
20210313 2121702
20210313 1779516
20210314 1381958
20210314 1389385
20210314 2523322
20210314 2086453
20210315 1194240
20210315 1205421
20210315 2184774
20210315 1813142
20210316 1194240
20210316 1205421
20210316 2184774
20210316 1813142
20210317 1194240
20210317 1205421
20210317 2184774
20210317 1813142

Comment: Expected output                                                                                                                    Date_Date Sum of Data
2021-03-02 6131235
2021-03-03 5984926
2021-03-04 5780859
2021-03-05 6131235
2021-03-06 5912568
2021-03-07 5858157
2021-03-08 5928221
2021-03-09 6131235
2021-03-10 5984926
2021-03-11 5780859
2021-03-12 6131235
2021-03-13 6131235
2021-03-14 6131235
2021-03-15 6131235
2021-03-16 6131235

Comment: Thank you, answer is edited, it is what you need?

Answer (score 1):

IIUC:

```
df['Data_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Data_Date'], format='%Y%m%d')

#get today Timestamp
today = pd.to_datetime('today').normalize()
#get previous days by length of rows in DataFrame
prev = today - pd.Timedelta(len(df), unit='d')

#generate new datetimes by range with starting datetime
df["new"] = pd.to_datetime(range(len(df)), unit='d', origin=prev)
```

---

```
print (df)

    Data_Date     Data        new
0  2021-03-11  1762439 2021-02-20
1  2021-03-12  1678808 2021-02-21
2  2021-03-12  1665741 2021-02-22
3  2021-03-12  3043567 2021-02-23
4  2021-03-12  2362461 2021-02-24
5  2021-03-13  1166616 2021-02-25
6  2021-03-13  1156903 2021-02-26
7  2021-03-13  2121702 2021-02-27
8  2021-03-13  1779516 2021-02-28
9  2021-03-14  1381958 2021-03-01
10 2021-03-14  1389385 2021-03-02
11 2021-03-14  2523322 2021-03-03
12 2021-03-14  2086453 2021-03-04
13 2021-03-15  1194240 2021-03-05
14 2021-03-15  1205421 2021-03-06
15 2021-03-15  2184774 2021-03-07
16 2021-03-15  1813142 2021-03-08
17 2021-03-16  1194240 2021-03-09
18 2021-03-16  1205421 2021-03-10
19 2021-03-16  2184774 2021-03-11
20 2021-03-16  1813142 2021-03-12
21 2021-03-17  1194240 2021-03-13
22 2021-03-17  1205421 2021-03-14
23 2021-03-17  2184774 2021-03-15
24 2021-03-17  1813142 2021-03-16
```